# How do I crop an image based on dark areas/noise?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, crop, noise-reduction

Lets say I have an image like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlsWB.jpg

I want to be able to find out the dark areas in the image and then crop the image so that I get a new rectangular image without any of the dark areas (that you see in the corners of the original image).

The final image would have to look something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXAuQ.jpg

Now the challenge here is that the dark areas are not all black pixels, nor are they all the same color. There is dark, slightly darker dark, slightly lighter dark if you get what I'm trying to say.

Would like to know if this is possible in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageProcessor library](http://imageprocessor.org/) has a function called [EntropyCrop](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/imagefactory/entropycrop/) that might be suitable. You can fiddle with the `threshold` parameter to tune the results.

If that doesn't work you can do something like this:

- Create a function that determines whether a pixel is dark or not
  (based on an adjustable intensity threshold)
- Add up all vectors (coordinates) of the pixels that aren't dark.
- Divide the result by the number of said pixels.
  This gives you the center of the disc/object.
- If the size of the object is known in advance, just crop with a rectangle of suitable size centered on that point.
- Otherwise start with a very small centered cropping rectangle and count the percentage of dark pixels in it.
- Progressively enlarge the rectangle until the percentage grows above an adjustable threshold.

Comment: I cant use the ImageProcessor library because I have to work with .net 3.5 :(

Comment: You can get the source from github and try to compile it on 3.5